# JSF Managed beans and decorate pattern

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

Is there any way to intercept the creation of a JSF backing bean to transparently decorate it?

I'm on Weblogic 10.3 with JDK 1.6, no CDI.

Perhaps subclassing the BeanManager class? But, how register the BeanManager extension to the weblogic jsf implementation?

Comment: Instead of creating a homegrown custom solution, not make the switch to CDI? Or search for a  generic 'interceptor' mechanism (not jsf managed beans specific)

Comment: @Kukeltje, because I have environment constraints from my client. I agree that Weblogic 10.3 and JDK 1.6 are obsolete technologies, but I have to use them.

Comment: I did not say to drop WL10.3 and jdk 1.6, I said try using CDI ;-) You could try adding it on that server. But it might not be supported

Comment: @Kukeltje, maybe I could, yes, but on WL10.3 it seems daunting :) I have read many posts on this and... it seems daunting and not guaranteed to work. Moreover, we have a large application in production. So, if someone knows how to create the "homegrown custom solution" I asked, I'd be happy.

Comment: then look for general solutions like aspectj (or successors, I did not keep track of those libraries lately)

Comment: What do you mean with `BeanManager class`?

Comment: I found a way to simulate the decoration using a custom ELResolver. It works. But I'm still curious, if someone knows a way to stretch the BeanManager, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: @XtremeBiker, I mean the com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager class that in some implementations drives the instantiation of a managed bean.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `@PostConstruct` annotation for your `init()` method. This will ensure correct one-shot JSF backing bean initialization.

Comment: Thanks @cgennari but I asked another thing.
I would substitute the managed bean with a proxy transparently during creation.